# how to pass string to a class with a button action

Tags: java, string, swing, selenium, user-interface

In Java, I have build a GUI class called dashboard.java with jtexfield and a jbutton, the action for jbutton is to get the text from jtexfield and store in a string. But I have another java class called testbot.java where It's a script and need to use the strings but I haven't found a way to pass the string to the from dashboard.java to testbot.java. I have searched but not found the answer to my question for passing the strings. Here below is how my code from my class dashboard.java looks like for the event of jbutton to store, but again I want it to also send the string to testbot.java class so I can use it there.

```
private void jButtonSaveMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
       // String profile;
        String Fname;
        String Sname;

        String email;
        String Phone;

        String address1;
        String address2;
        String zip;
        String City;
        String Country;

        String Creditcard;
        String CVV;
        String Year;
        String Month;
        String Type;


        Fname=jTextFirstname.getText();
        Sname=jTextSecondname.getText();

        email=jTextEmail.getText();
        Phone=jTextPhonenumber.getText();

        address1=jTextAddress1.getText();
        address2=jTextAddress2.getText();
        zip=jTextZipcode.getText();
        City=jTextCity.getText();
        Country=(String) jCombocuntry.getSelectedItem();
        Creditcard=jTextcreditnumber.getText();
        CVV=jTextCVV.getText();
        Year=(String) jComboYear.getSelectedItem();
        Month=(String) jCombomonth.getSelectedItem();
        Type=(String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();


        //String sprofile;
        //sprofile=jComboBox5.insertItemAt()

        //System.out.println(Type); tested combobox val sen print

             //knappen kmr ta info
             jLabel12.setText("saved");

    }
```

Comment: For better, sooner help post [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

First of all, separate your concerns: your mouse listener method shouldn't contain so much code. Instead, you should write helper methods that "pull" together the required information. And ideally you don't keep just 10 different variables, you **start** by defining classes that represent a User, an Address and such things. And then you pass around instances of these classes.

And "how to pass on", boils down to: by having something to pass to!

In other words: your method `jButtonSaveMouseClicked()` exists in a class that owns all these UI elements (probably a JFrame or something). That class could also have a field of that class TestBot. And then you simply invoke methods on that other class whenever you need to. You see, your frame knows about other objects, such as `jTextFirstname`. That allows you to call methods on that objects. Your test bot would be no different to that.

Going one step further: your approach sounds wrong. Your UI should **not** know that there is a "test bot" around that probably is there to *test* the UI itself. The more "real world" solution works differently: that class that you want to notify a specific other class (that TestBot) should instead allow to register **listeners**. Then the testbot can register itself *to* the dashboard, and whenever the dashboard wants to, it can notify its listener about some change.

In other words: avoid a that "the thing to test" depends on "the tester". It should work the other way round.

Comment: Do you mean that I should create another class for the dashboard.java class to store and then the testbot.java is going to read to from there? Sorry, but programming is not something I'm good at yet.